# Работа с файлами в СИ. Ввод файлов с клавиатуры

Tags: c, файлы, указатели, файловый-ввод-вывод

Новичок в си и не знаю как сделать такое задание:

- имена файлов исходных данных (в режимах начального формирования и добавления) и файлов результатов должны вводиться с клавиатуры;
- при отсутствии на диске указанного файла в режимах чтения и добавления на экран должно выдаваться предупреждающее сообщение и осуществляться повторный запрос имени файла.

С такой программой:

```
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<math.h>

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1251");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int A[10];
    int i;
    int* p = A;

    FILE* vvod = fopen("info.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        *(p + i) = rand();
    }
    fprintf(vvod, "Массив из 10 чиесел:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fprintf(vvod, "%d) %d\n", i + 1, *(p + i));
    }
    fclose(vvod);

    char line[50];
    FILE* vivod = fopen("info.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        fgets(line, 50, vivod);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(vivod);

    int N = 0;
    int masi[20] = {0};
    FILE* raschot1 = fopen("info1.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (*(A + i) % 10 == 0) {
            fprintf(raschot1, "%d\n", i+1);
            N++;
        }
    }
    fclose(raschot1);

    FILE* rez = fopen("info.txt", "a");
    FILE* vivod1 = fopen("info1.txt", "r");
    int r;
    char* number[10];
    for (r = 0; r < N; r++) {
        fgets(number, 10, vivod1);
        printf("Число оканчивающиеся на 0 под номером: %s", number);
        fprintf(rez, "Число оканчивающиеся на 0 под номером: %s\n", number);
    }
    fclose(vivod1);
    fclose(rez);

    int B[6][5], b, d;
    FILE* vvod2 = fopen("info2.txt", "w");
    printf("\nБаллы, которые набрали спортсмены в каждом виде спорта:\n");
    for (d = 0; d < 6; d++) {
        for (b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
            *(*(B + d) + b) = rand() % 10;
            fprintf(vvod2, "%d\t", *(*(B + d) + b));
        }
        fprintf(vvod2, "\n");
    }
    fclose(vvod2);

    char* line2[20];
    FILE* rez1 = fopen("info.txt", "a");
    FILE* vivod2 = fopen("info2.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        fgets(line2, 20, vivod2);
        printf("%s", line2);
        fprintf(rez1, "%s", line2);
    }
    fclose(vivod2);
    fclose(rez1);

    int j, sum[6] = { 0 }, min = 100000, max = 0;
    int* sm = sum;
    int* mi = &min;
    int* ma = &max;
    FILE* raschot2 = fopen("info3.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            *(sum + i) += *(*(B + i) + j);
        }
        if (*(sum + i) > *ma) {
            *ma = *(sum + i);
        }
        if (*(sum + i) < *mi) {
            *mi = *(sum + i);
        }
    }
    fprintf(raschot2, "%d, %d", *mi, *ma);
    fclose(raschot2);

    char* number1[10];
    FILE* vivod3 = fopen("info3.txt", "r");
    fgets(number1, 10, vivod3);
    printf("Количество баллов набранное спортсменами, занявшими последнее и первое место соответственно: %s \n", number1);
    fclose(vivod3);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: считать имя файла можно с помощью `char fname[128];fgets(fname,128,stdin);` если `fopen` вернул `NULL`, значит не получилось.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Можете написать пример? А то у меня что-то не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто сделал вот так и всё работает:

```
    FILE* vvod;
    printf("Введите имя файла: ");
    scanf("%s", i1);
    while (((vvod = fopen(i1, "r")) == NULL))

    {
        printf("Неверное имя файла, повторите попытку: ");
        scanf("%s", i1);
    }
    fclose(vvod);

        vvod = fopen(i1, "w");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            *(p + i) = rand();
        }
        fprintf(vvod, "Массив из 10 чиесел:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            fprintf(vvod, "%d) %d\n", i + 1, *(p + i));
        }
        fclose(vvod);`
```

Comment: кажется `scanf` не примет имя файла с пробелами.

Answer (score 0):

Пример открытия файла, связанной с файловым указателем `vvod` :

```
FILE  * vvod  ;
enum  { fnamesize = 0x100 } ;
// локальный буфер для имени файла
char  fname [ fnamesize ] ;
char * rf ;
do  {
  fputs ( "Введите имя файла : "  , stdout  ) ;
  rf = fgets ( fname , fnamesize , stdin ) ;
  if ( rf ) {
    // удаляем в конце перевод строки '\n'
    size_t  l = strlen ( fname ) ;
    if ( l > 0 && fname [ l - 1 ] == '\n' )
      fname [ l - 1 ] = '\00' ;
    // открываем файл для записи
    vvod  = fopen ( fname , "w" ) ;
  }
  if ( rf == NULL || vvod == NULL )
    fprintf ( stderr  ,
      "Файла с именем '%s' не удалось открыть"
      " для записи, повторите попытку\n" , fname ) ;
} while ( rf == NULL || vvod  ==  NULL  ) ;
```

---

*У вас массивы `char * var [ N ] ;` определяют массивы *указателей*, а не строки букв. Это надо исправить.*

```
//char* number[10];
char  number  [ 10  ] ;
//char* line2[20];
char  line2 [ 20  ] ;
//char* number1[10];
char  number1 [ 10  ] ;
```

Comment: *`"enum  { fnamesize = 0x100 }"` ???*  В  limits.h для этих целей определена константа `PATH_MAX`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но сначала выдавало ошибку. Я написал vvod=fopen("info.txt", "w"). Если я пишу правильное название, то всё работает хорошо. Но если пишу другое, то программа создаёт этот файл и пишет в консоли какую-то ерунду.